# DB2 syntax error "DAYOFWEEK_ISO" when running H2 (in DB2 mode)

Tags: groovy, db2, h2

I have the following query which works nice when running directly against DB2:

```
SELECT 
RTRIM(CHAR(YR_I)) || RTRIM(CHAR(CASE WHEN MO_I = 1 THEN 1 WHEN MO_I = 2 THEN 1 WHEN MO_I = 3 THEN 1 WHEN MO_I = 4 THEN 1 WHEN MO_I = 5 THEN 1 WHEN MO_I = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)) || RTRIM(CHAR(QTR_I)) || (case when MO_I < 10 then rtrim(char(0)) || rtrim(char(MO_I)) else rtrim(char(MO_I)) end) || (case when WK_I < 10 then rtrim(char(0)) || rtrim(char(WK_I)) else rtrim(char(WK_I)) end)
AS ACCT_DATE_PER_I 
FROM DB2.FCST_DATE
WHERE ACCT_D = (current_date  - DAYOFWEEK_ISO(current_date) DAYS - 7 DAYS) with ur
```

But when I run it through a test with H2 as database with the following configuration:

```
      driverclassname: org.h2.Driver
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;mode=DB2
      username: test
      password:
```

I get the following error message:

`org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL`

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "DAYOFWEEK_ISO" not found; SQL statement: <SQL STATEMENT>
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readJavaFunction(Parser.java:2699) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFunction(Parser.java:2756) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3102) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2579) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2370) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTerm(Parser.java:3252) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readFactor(Parser.java:2587) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readSum(Parser.java:2574) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readConcat(Parser.java:2544) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readCondition(Parser.java:2499) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readAnd(Parser.java:2342) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readExpression(Parser.java:2334) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2291) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:2133) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1946) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1919) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:463) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:335) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:307) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:278) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:611) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:549) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1247) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:78) ~[h2-1.4.197.jar:1.4.197]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:433) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
```

Edit* my question is how do I solve for it. However with research I found out that i cannot orchestrate some of the DB specific functions in H2.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking why you are receiving this error, it's because you are using a DB2-specific function `DAYOFWEEK_ISO` which does not exist for an H2 database.

If you are asking how to resolve this error, you cannot as long as you are using database-specific queries (in your case, for DB2) against a different database type.  If you have hibernate in your application, you could use HQL instead so that your queries will be generic (usually) and work against different database types (usually).  If not, or if you need to keep this specific query then you can check for environment type and use mock data for testing rather than trying to work with your database.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found this out the hard way, I now have 2 choices, substitute the `DAYOFWEEK_ISO` by creating the value in java and pass it as an argument for the query or I have to run these tests on an test db and delete these records in teardown.